# APNS in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Could you please tell me the best practice to use fetchCompletionHandler when receiving the remote notification in the function :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
```

I saw people normally write this code at the end of the above function:

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

What if I write :

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
```

Or what happens even when I don't put the above code?

Note: I am using xcode7.1, objective-c, ios9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData** - Called when new content has been    fetched, and the application has been updated.
> - **UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData** - Called when the fetch for new    content went through, but no content is available.
> - **UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed** - Useful for error handling, this is    called when the fetch was unable to go through.

You have to call this to let iOS know what the result of your background fetch was. It uses this information to schedule future background fetches.

If you neglect to do this, future backgrund fetches may be delayed by the OS.

An example of good use is [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/).

**Update**: The consequences of not calling this handler might include terminating your app altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, how can I decide I need to pass UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData, NoData, or Failed?

Comment: if you received the remote notification and according to your logic you received the content needed to update your app you can send  UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData

If the notifications are received and the content is not available (in case of generic notifications and content not supported by your app) you can send UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData

and if it fails during fetching of data you can send UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed

Proper use if these make your App more efficient in background.